# Flash "settings" context menu is unavailable on local player

Tags: flash, settings, microphone

I need my flash movie to have access to the microphone, but it is refusing to display the confirmation dialog and the "Settings" context menu item is disabled. The document size *is* adequate to display the dialog, though. The catch, though, this is only occurring when the SWF is run in the local player. If I run the SWF in a browser, it asks properly and the settings menu is available. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. 
In my case parameter "wmode" caused the problem described above. It was set to "direct" value and after removing the parameter the problem was solved.
Try to remove it or just change its value.

Comment: wmode is only available when you test in a browser - he said, that he couldn't see the dialog testing in the flashplayer

Answer (score 0):

You need a minimum size of 138px in height and about 180px in width for the box to display, if you don't it won't show up